# Which latest version of kotlin is compatible with the latest version of compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created a Compose for Desktop project in IDEA Intellij.

When doing the Build to generate the .jar artifact, IDEA presents the following error:

`Kotlin: The provided plugin androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposePluginRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler. java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposePluginRegistrar does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void registerProjectComponents(com.intellij.mock.MockProject, org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.CompilerConfiguration)' of interface org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.ComponentRegistrar. at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli_base(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:689) at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.registerExtensionsFromPlugins(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:164) at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.configureProjectEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:587) at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:194) at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt)`

My gradle.properties like this:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
> kotlin.code.style=official
> kotlin.version=1.9.22
> compose.version=1.5.10

My gradle.properties like this:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
> kotlin.code.style=official
> kotlin.version=1.9.22
> compose.version=1.5.10

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

Answer (score 2):

As of I am writing this answer latest Compose Compiler Version `1.5.10` with Compatible Kotlin Version `1.9.22`

You can refer this official docs for [Compose to Kotlin Compatibility Map](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)

Comment: This is the way it is defined in my project and with Java SDK 21, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There are three version-numbers to consider:

```
ext {
    kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    kotlin_compiler_extension_version = '1.5.10'
    androidx_compose_bom_version = '2024.02.02'
}
```

The [BOM to library version mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping) says the "compose version" would be `1.6.3`.

Also see: [Using the Bill of Materials](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom).

Comment: Where should I configure this in my compose for desktop intellij project?